# sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, gradle

I try to use **compileSdkVerion** 21 and **targetSdkVersion** 21.
See the second picture bellow, my project just compileSdkVersion 21 and library at version 21. How value-23, value-24 and value-26 exist there?
I have tried many ways:

1. Delete build folder
2. Uninstall/install sdk plaform
3. Clean/Rebuild will get error bellow.

[image: Configuaration]
[image: Can't clean project]

Comment: try to update **compileSdkVersion : 27.0.2** your problem will be resolved.

Comment: My manager only want the project run with compileSdkversion 21.

Comment: Android Studio 3.1.2 required compileSdkVersion  more than 27.

Answer (score 1):

These are the Only solution for it:-
 1. Deprecate your android studio.
 2. Use only lib 23 build element 
 3. Don't use this element like this

compile RecyclerView'27.0.1'

use only

compile RecyclerView'23.0.0'